# Converting Object to JSON and JSON to Object in PHP, (library like Gson for Java)

Tags: php, gson, json

I am developing a web application in PHP,

I need to transfer many objects from server as JSON string, is there any library existing for PHP to convert object to JSON and JSON String to Objec, like Gson library for Java.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This should do the trick!

```
// convert object => json
$json = json_encode($myObject);

// convert json => object
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Here's an example

```
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->hello = "world";
$foo->bar = "baz";

$json = json_encode($foo);
echo $json;
//=> {"hello":"world","bar":"baz"}

print_r(json_decode($json));
// stdClass Object
// (
//   [hello] => world
//   [bar] => baz
// )
```

If you want the output as an Array instead of an Object, pass `true` to `json_decode`

```
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
// Array
// (
//   [hello] => world
//   [bar] => baz
// )
```

More about [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

See also: [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: one problem I am dealing with now is -- using json_decode(), I get an stdClass object, not my original object.  I could use serialize/unserialize, but my objects change structure over time even if slightly, rendering serialize unusable.

Comment: @Dennis `unserialize` will always return an instance of `stdClass`, this does not make it unusable. You could easily design you API to support something like `$attrs = unserialize($json); $person = new Person($attrs);` Your `Person` constructor can then assign the attributes accordingly.

Answer (score 30):

for more extendability for large scale apps use oop style with encapsulated fields.

Simple way :-

```
  class Fruit implements JsonSerializable {

        private $type = 'Apple', $lastEaten = null;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->lastEaten = new DateTime();
        }

        public function jsonSerialize() {
            return [
                'category' => $this->type,
                'EatenTime' => $this->lastEaten->format(DateTime::ISO8601)
            ];
        }
    }
```

echo json_encode(new Fruit()); //which outputs:

```
{"category":"Apple","EatenTime":"2013-01-31T11:17:07-0500"}
```

Real Gson on PHP :-

1. http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer
2. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html
3. http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.serializer.html
4. http://fractal.thephpleague.com/ - serialize only

Comment: with using json the problem is the reverse part because jeson_decode only returns an stdClass object. You would need to be able to initialize an object of your class by providing an array of fieldvalues. Way too much overhead. just use plain serialize.

Answer (score 6):

```
json_decode($json, true); 
// the second param being true will return associative array. This one is easy.
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP8-Code:

```php
class foo{
    function __construct(
        public $bar,
        protected $bat,
        private $baz,
    ){}

    function getBar(){return $this->bar;}
    function getBat(){return $this->bat;}
    function getBaz(){return $this->baz;}
}

//Create Object
$foo = new foo(bar:"bar", bat:"bat", baz:"baz");

//Object => JSON
$fooJSON = json_encode(serialize($foo));
print_r($fooJSON);
// "O:3:\"foo\":3:{s:3:\"bar\";s:3:\"bar\";s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000bat\";s:3:\"bat\";s:8:\"\u0000foo\u0000baz\";s:3:\"baz\";}"

// Important. In order to be able to unserialize() an object, the class of that object needs to be defined.
#   More information here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php
//JSON => Object
$fooObject = unserialize(json_decode($fooJSON));
print_r($fooObject);
//(
#    [bar] => bar
#    [bat:protected] => bat
#    [baz:foo:private] => baz
# )

//To use some functions or Properties of $fooObject
echo $fooObject->bar;
// bar

echo $fooObject->getBat();
// bat

echo $fooObject->getBaz();
// baz
```

Comment: `json_encode(serialize($foo))` and `unserialize(json_decode($fooJSON)` also work in PHP 7

Answer (score 0):

I made a method to solve this. 
My approach is:

1 - Create a abstract class that have a method to convert Objects to Array (including private attr) using Regex.
2 - Convert the returned array to json.

I use this Abstract class as parent of all my domain classes

Class code:

```
namespace Project\core;

abstract class AbstractEntity {
    public function getAvoidedFields() {
        return array ();
    }
    public function toArray() {
        $temp = ( array ) $this;

        $array = array ();

        foreach ( $temp as $k => $v ) {
            $k = preg_match ( '/^\x00(?:.*?)\x00(.+)/', $k, $matches ) ? $matches [1] : $k;
            if (in_array ( $k, $this->getAvoidedFields () )) {
                $array [$k] = "";
            } else {

                // if it is an object recursive call
                if (is_object ( $v ) && $v instanceof AbstractEntity) {
                    $array [$k] = $v->toArray();
                }
                // if its an array pass por each item
                if (is_array ( $v )) {

                    foreach ( $v as $key => $value ) {
                        if (is_object ( $value ) && $value instanceof AbstractEntity) {
                            $arrayReturn [$key] = $value->toArray();
                        } else {
                            $arrayReturn [$key] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    $array [$k] = $arrayReturn;
                }
                // if it is not a array and a object return it
                if (! is_object ( $v ) && !is_array ( $v )) {
                    $array [$k] = $v;
                }
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```