# How to iterate the JSON data into a loop using PHP?

Tags: php, json

I need to iterate some JSON formatted data into loop using PHP. My JSON data is below:

```
{  
   "question1":{  
      "ques":"questin1",
      "optional":[  
         {  
            "opt":"option1"
         },
         {  
            "opt":"option2"
         }
      ]
   },
   "question2":{  
      "ques":"questin2",
      "optional":[  
         {  
            "opt":"option1"
         },
         {  
            "opt":"option2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I need to run the loop so that the result data will come in above format using PHP.

Comment: So you just want to print out your json?! Or what does "above format" mean?

Comment: Did you try [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) ?

Comment: @JimmyKo : Actually those json format is not my input but it should be the output after loop has completed.

Comment: Then show your current data and loop

Comment: i can use those data which are present in that json .its should be total printed output.

Comment: So you got an array or what?

Comment: @Rizier123 : i am little bit confused about the loop to produce the above type format. here i need one perfect loop to print the result.

Comment: Show your current code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115713/discussion-between-satya-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the php object to json object using json_encode

```
// convert object => json
$json = json_encode($myObject);
```

This might helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858457/6285410

Answer (score -1):

What you showed us is a Possible JSON Data. In this Format, we can do nothing with it in PHP except by decoding back into Native PHP Object. Once that is done, You can access all the Properties of the Object like you do with normal PHP Object like `$objData->questin1`. Here's what is meant with the above statements:

```
    <?php

        $strJson = '{
           "question1":{
              "ques":"questin1",
              "optional":[
                 {
                    "opt":"option1"
                 },
                 {
                    "opt":"option2"
                 }
              ]
           },
           "question2":{
              "ques":"questin2",
              "optional":[
                 {
                    "opt":"option1"
                 },
                 {
                    "opt":"option2"
                 }
              ]
           }
        }';

        $objData    = json_decode($strJson);
        var_dump($objData);


        // NOW, TO GET AT EACH OF THE PROPERTIES OF THE OBJECT IS EASY...

        // ACCESS THE question1 OR question2
        $q1     = $objData->question1;
        $q2     = $objData->question2;

        // ACCESS THE que WITHIN question 1 OR question2
        $k1     = $objData->question1->ques;        //  EQUIVALENT TO: $q1->ques
        $k2     = $objData->question2->ques;        //  EQUIVALENT TO: $q2->ques

        // ACCESS THE optional ARRAY INSIDE OF question 1 OR question2
        $opt1   = $objData->question1->optional;    //  EQUIVALENT TO: $q1->optional
        $opt2   = $objData->question2->optional;    //  EQUIVALENT TO: $q2->optional

        var_dump($q1, $q2, $k1, $k2, $opt1, $opt2);


    ?>
```