# Converting JSON to an Object

Tags: c#, php, json, json.net

i have a method that sends a `POST` Request to my PHP API and the API responds with a JSON String return value.

however after using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to the JSON result, i am getting this format

```
{[
  {
    "usr_name": "12-34567",
    "usr_fullname": "LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME",
    "usr_emailaddress": "myemail@mail.com",
    "photo_url": "http://mywebsite.com/fetch_photo.php?id=MTItNDA1MDY=",
    "token": "64c420939814c62889ea143d17736841"
  }  
]}
```

however i am not able to `Deserialize` it to my Class that is structured like below

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string usr_name { get; set; }
    public string usr_fullname { get; set; }
    public string usr_emailaddress { get; set; }
    public string photo_url { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
}
```

i am using Newtonsoft JSON.Net for this purpose, this is my first time dealing with JSON inside C# so i am quite clueless no how or what to do. i've done several research only to find outdated tutorials or questions unlike my returned JSON value

so the php's response looks like this 
[image]

and after trying to deserialize it, it looks like this
[image]

Comment: you have an object containing an array which contains single object. whatever you deserialize to, your "myobject" only exists 2 levels down inside that decoded object.

Comment: @TheQuestioner may be this link will help you
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858448/converting-object-to-json-and-json-to-object-in-php-library-like-gson-for-java]

Comment: try deseiralizing the json into `MyObject[]` not `MyObject`

Comment: @hellowstone it worked. although is there any way i can eliminate the unwanted single-indexed array ?

Comment: If you cannot change the response JSON, best way is to assign the first index of the array to a new object. `var myObj = myObject[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json string is not valid json - the wrapping `{}` are invalid. You should check how the json string is generated / encoded inside your php API.

Comment: apparently i have no control over how the JSON result is generated since the api i am using was only provided to me without any further documentation except comments pointing out example paramenters for each function inside the said api

Comment: This was in the low quality review queue, but I'm voting to keep it here because it legitimately answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, I'd say you serialized this object in PHP from a database query, which typically returns an array of rows. Which is why your JSON is an object with an array that contains an object.

There's an extra level of indirection in there so you need to remove that to deserialize. Try using [`array_pop`](http://php.net/array-pop) in your PHP to to make sure you're only serializing a single object, or just use the `fetch` rather than `fetchAll` equivalent for your database interface in PHP if you only expect a single value. Otherwise, iterate over the array of objects after deserializing in C#.

Comment: to be honest, i don't know how i could answer your question. because the PHP API that i am using was provided to me. The api would then fetch data from the database according to a function i call from the api.php. and the result's json would then be formatted like this => `[{"usr_name":"12-34567","usr_fullname":"LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME","usr_emailaddress":"myemail@mail.com","photo_url":"http:\/\/mywebsite.com\/fetch_photo.php?id=MTItNDA1D2DMDY=","token":"64c420939814c62889ea143d17736841"}]`

Comment: I didn't realize I had asked a question. I was fairly certain this was the answer section, but if you have control over both the PHP code as well as the C# code it's dealer's choice at this point. Either way to solve the problem you need to remove the extra level of indirection in one place or another.

Comment: can you please give me a walkthrough on how i can achieve this ?

Comment: Where? In PHP or in C#? In PHP if what you're getting back is the actual JSON string, like you say, just `json_decode()`, `array_pop()`, and `json_encode()` again. In C# you'll need to deserialize to a `List`, something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(List<string>>(json)`, iterate over that and inside your loop you'll have the object.

Comment: when i'm trying to `json_decode` in `PHP` i get this error http://i.imgur.com/c5P5oT3.png

Comment: That wasn't a result of `json_decode`. If you look at line 13 of the script home.php where the error message explicitly tells you the error occurred, you'll probably find that you tried to `echo`/`print` a variable that was an array and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

That can be a soultion for that in PHP (if your json example is right):

```
$obj = new MyClass();//get empty instance
$arr = json_decode(trim($json,'}{'),true);//get array from json, but fix it first
//because {[{'key':'value'}]} is not valid!
$arr = $arr[0];//get sub array with real data
//bind all data to your object
array_walk($arr,function($v,$k) use ($obj){ $obj->{$k}=$v; });

print $obj->usr_name;// output: 12-34567
```

Why is `{[{'key':'value'}]}` not valid? 
An Object Member MUST have a name!

So that would be valid json: `{'content':[{'key':'value'}]}`.

UPDATE: Forget this answer!! You want to do this in C# not in PHP :)