# How to convert object format to json format in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, array-unique

I'm using `array_unique` to remove the duplicate values but it returns an object format.

```
$event = array_unique($array_event);
```

output as

```
{"0":{"title":"new","description":"hai"},"4":null}
```

Excepted output:

```
[{"title":"new","description":"hai"},null}]
```

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: `$event = array_values(array_unique($array_event));`

Comment: thanks you. now its working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Object to JSON and JSON to Object in PHP, (library like Gson for Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858448/converting-object-to-json-and-json-to-object-in-php-library-like-gson-for-java)

Comment: @TravisHeeter not duplicate, refered only advises use of `json_encode` which it self those not produce the required output in this case

Comment: @RaghulRajendran you shoud mention in question that your are asking about the json_encod-ed output `json_encode($event)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud reindex result before `json_encode`

```
$event = array_values(array_unique($array_event));
```