# convert string into array for highcharts js

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

My code PHP generate a string variable

```
<?php
foreach($rows as $row){

    $result .= "['" .$row["Name"]."'," .$row['Value']. "] , ";
}

$result = rtrim($result, ' , ');

//echo $result returns: ['FirstName1 LastName1',10] , ['FirstName2 LastName2',12] , ['FirstName3 LastName3 ',40]

?>
```

In js how can I convert the 'name' variable into a functional variable for 'data:' ?

```
<script>
var name = "<?php echo $result; ?>";

Highcharts.chart('container', {
...

data: [
    ['Shanghai', 23.7],
    ['Lagos', 16.1],
    ['Istanbul', 14.2]
  ];

...
});
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9858448/266535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `$result` in an array:

```
$result = "[$result]";
```

But you really should use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like this:

```
$resultArr = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $resultArr[] = [$row['Name'], $row['Value']];
}
$result = json_encode($resultArr);
```

Comment: Does not work because $row['Value'] is string, I need number: 9 not "9". Thank you!