# What is the best way to cast a JSON into a multidimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to cast a JSON into a multidimensional array in Java.
The JSON structure is similar to this one:

```
[0][0]{'key1'->'value1'}
[0][0]{'key2'->'value2'}
[0][1]{'key1'->'value1'}
[1][0]{'key1'->'value1'}
```

The following works :

```
HashMap[][] data = new Gson().fromJson(response, HashMap[][].class);
```

But of course, I get this warning:

> Raw use of parameterized class 'HashMap'

I tried :

```
private HashMap<String, String>[][] data = new Gson().fromJson(response, HashMap<String, String>[][].class);
```

But this syntax is not allowed.

What is the best way to cast a JSON into a multidimensional array in Java?

Comment: What is it now, PHP? Java? Both have libraries for that.

Comment: try with wildcard ?

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan It actually works with wildcards. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

you can use  in java the next

Example the json

> {
> "PED": {
> "arrArticulos": [
> [
> 50,
> 10
> ],
> [
> 51,
> 9
> ],
> [
> 52,
> 8
> ],
> [
> 51,
> 9
> ]
> ],
> "md5Passwd": "123",
> "txtUser": "123",
> "fun": "enviarPedido"
> } }

Class  in java

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//JSON file to Java object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(json()), Staff.class);
```

Class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.examen.navegacion;

/**
 *
 * @author wilso
 */
public class Staff {
    int[][] arrArticulos;
}
```

In php you can do the next

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858448/converting-object-to-json-and-json-to-object-in-php-library-like-gson-for-java][1]